# I install pyaudio many times But not working? ERROR: Cannot uninstall 'PyAudio'

Tags: module, pyaudio

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyaudio'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "c:\Users\Omkar_Bhatuse\Downloads\VoiceBot\Voice_bot.py", line 15, in 
with sr.Microphone() as source:
File "C:\Users\Omkar_Bhatuse\Downloads\VoiceBot\venv\lib\site-packages\speech_recognition_*init*_.py", line 79, in **init**
self.pyaudio_module = self.get_pyaudio()
File "C:\Users\Omkar_Bhatuse\Downloads\VoiceBot\venv\lib\site-packages\speech_recognition_*init*_.py", line 110, in get_pyaudio
raise AttributeError("Could not find PyAudio; check installation")
AttributeError: Could not find PyAudio; check installation
(venv) PS C:\Users\Omkar_Bhatuse\Downloads\VoiceBot>

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

install it using command prompt then try to use the package from the site-packages folder in the python interrupter